# Red5: Server application skeleton and helloworld

Tags: apache-flex, red5

Can anyone provide an updated application skeleton for a Red5 application? From what I have found the logging system changed from Log4j. I've been looking for some tutorials just to setup everything but can't really find something that simply works.
In addiction, can anyone provide a simple tutorial with a server application and Flex client?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I struggled a lot with that.. This reference worked for me:

http://fossies.org/unix/privat/red5-1.0.0-RC2.tar.gz:a/red5-1.0.0/doc/reference/html/logging-setup.html

The trick was to Remove any log4j.properties or log4j.xml files and Remove any "log4j" listeners from the web.xml

Create a logback-myApp.xml where myApp is the name for your webapp and place it on your webapp classpath (WEB-INF/classes or in your application jar within WEB-INF/lib)

and im my app i did:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.red5.logging.Red5LoggerFactory;
```

and then:

```
private static Logger log = Red5LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClassName.class, "myApp");
```

the clients actionscript looks like this:

```
// Initializiing Connection
        private function initConnection():void{
            nc = new NetConnection();
            nc.client = new NetConnectionClient();  
            nc.objectEncoding = flash.net.ObjectEncoding.AMF0;                  
            nc.connect(rtmpPath.text,true); //Path to FMS Server e.g. rtmp://<hostname>/<application name>

            nc.addEventListener("netStatus", publishStream);    //Listener to see if connection is successful
        }


    private function publishStream(event:NetStatusEvent):void{
        if(nc.connected){
            nsPublish = new NetStream(nc);  //Initializing NetStream
            nsPublish.attachCamera(Camera.getCamera());
            nsPublish.attachAudio(Microphone.getMicrophone()); //Attaching Camera & Microphone
            nsPublish.publish(streamName.text,'live'); //Publish stream
            mx.controls.Alert.show("Published");
        }
        else{
            mx.controls.Alert.show("Connection Error");
        }
    }
```